# Structure definition with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm practicing structures in C, and I come up with this doubt. Sometimes I see something like:

```
struct myStruct{
     //some data
} *p;
```

What does that pointer `p` means?

How is that different from:

```
struct myStruct{
    //some data
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
struct myStruct{
    //some data
};
```

is the definition of the `struct`. There is no *variable* created with that data type.

On the other hand,

```
struct myStruct{
     //some data
} *p;
```

is the definition of the `struct` as well as creating a variable `p` of type pointer-to-`struct`. After allocating memory to `p`, you can access the member variables using that pointer.

Comment: does that mean that `struct myStruct{ //some data } *p;` is equivalent to `struct myStruct{ //some data };`  followed by  `struct myStruct *p;` ?